# Are T1 and T0 inheritable in the subspace and product topologies?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

T2-ness property is inherited in subspaces and in the topological product. What about T1 and T0, are they inheritable? Can someone give simple examples when this happens and when this does not happen, ie of Ti being inheritable , not inheritable in both the product and the subspace topology for i=0,1?

Comment: What happens when you try to prove these?  That is what you should do, and report on it here, before you can expect us to do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: For both properties, you can show that they are inherited by subspaces and products immediately using the definition (for product, use the fact that if two points are distinct, then they differ on a coordinate).